# Transfer PanGesture to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to start pan gesture in 1 item. And at the instant the gesture is recognized I create a new item view at the exact same spot and transfer the pan gesture to the new item so the new hovering item moves with the fingers.

How can I do this?

Here is the code so far:

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(useItemPanGesture(_:)))
item.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func useItemPanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let newView = createView()
    newView.addPanGesture(target: self, action: #selector(self.actualPanGesture(panGesture)))
    panGesture.enabled = false
}

func actualPanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
     //do pan gesture stuff
}
```

I have trouble in the transfer of the pan gesture. Line starting with newView.addPangesture.
 [image]

Comment: What control are you using to view these items ? CollectionView ?

Comment: So you have placed multiple views on your viewContoller ?

Comment: I have itemVC and in that itemView which is UIScrollView. All the views are in the UIScrollView. (The bottom part of the inventor)